# RabbitMQ: fanout exchange to topic exchange binding with routing key

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a rather specific question.
My use case requires me to bind a fanout exchange to a topic exchange, which is straight forward. The problem is I need to "include" a routing key while transitioning exchanges as follows:

```
published on fanout exchange:
 routing_key: "" (or any, fanout exchanges don't care)
 message: "foo"
↓
binding with fixed routing key "bar"
↓
received on topic exchange:
 routing:key: "bar"
 message: "foo"
```

From RabbitMQ docs I can't find anything useful regarding my problem.

⁓ phil

Comment: Are you trying to change the original message routing key with another specific "bar" one before it reaches your topic exchange? To my knowledge there is no way to do that. If that is indeed what you want to do, I'd use an intermediate queue, and from there grab and modify the messages, handling the modification there, most likely with a [static shovel](https://www.rabbitmq.com/docs/shovel-static) although other options are also available.

Comment: @Olivier yes, that is exactly what I tried to do. I thought about a similar solution but was worried about processing/time overhead since I am somewhat of timing constrained. Too bad there is no proper solution. Thanks for your suggestion tho!